# What's the difference between these two bash parallelization syntax?

Tags: bash

Value "4" below is the number of CPU threads. Idea is to run the tasks in batch of 4 and wait until the current batch is finished before starting the next batch.

Syntax 1:

```
while read something; do
((++i%4==0)) && wait
(
 task using something as input;
)
done < input_file.txt
```

Syntax 2:

```
while read something; do
((i=i%4)); ((i++==0)) && wait
(
 task using something as input;
)
done < input_file.txt
```

To me they both work the same except the second one is longer. But when running in the cloud (AWS ubuntu 14.04), only syntax 1 worked. The syntax2 threw a generic syntax error at "((i=i%4));" step and it became a mystery.

Comment: Neither is parallelizing anything, at least not as shown.

Comment: In the first one the value of `i` is just `++i` incremented each loop. In second one the value of `i` is always lower then `4` in `i=i%4`. `generic syntax error at "((i=i%4));"` - please post the exact error message. bash doesn't throws a "generic syntax error" - it says for example `bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<the token>'`

Comment: Statements like `((i++==0))` that could serve as coding quizzes ("what's the output of...") are usually a red flag. Good luck understanding this in two weeks ;)

Comment: I learned the code from the bottom of "https://lab.rolisoft.net/blog/parallelization-of-commands-in-bash.html" and tried it. I should have said that the generic syntax error was no error but the code simply quit which caused the job to error out with no specific error message or exit code. The only thing I know was that the job log ended at ((i=i%4)) and I think it's because it was treated as a command which is not a valid command but that did not explain why the other shorter syntax "((++i%4==0)) && wait" worked.

Answer (score 0):

"The second one is longer" doesn't help since you used pseudocode.

Maybe this will help:

```
while read x; do ((i=++i%4)) || wait; sleep $x & done < input_file.txt
```

My `input_file.txt`:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```